# Как учить react

Tags: reactjs

Посоветуйте пожалуйста ресурсы или книги для изучения сего чуда :)*

Comment: @Istinnavvine, https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/info

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Я бы в основном выделил то, что стоит начать учить на классовых компонентах, а не на хуках (несмотря на то, что комьюнити стремительно переходит к последним). Потому как все равно придется работать еще продолжительный период и с проектами на классовых.

Что касается ресурсов, несмотря на банальность ответа я бы очень советовал именно сам [React](https://ru.reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). Потому как там наиболее актуальная информация и на русском языке. Есть не просто документация, но и специальный раздел для введения

Comment: Начать можно как раз на хуках, чтобы понять, как лучше. А потом можно на классовых ... в сочетании с коболом.